# Cleartool removing a checkedout file from a folder with rmname

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

How can I use cleartool rmname to remove a file, that is checkedout by some one else, from a folder? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command-line `cleartool rname -force` is only necessary when the file is checked out in another branch.

That allows to bypass the error message: 'file' has checkouts

[image: Error message]

In that case, you need to check out the parent directory first, `rmname`, and then don't forget to check in the parent directory, or your file will still be visible by others.

See more at the technote ["About cleartool rmname and checkouts"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21232758)

> There is a `-force` option available for `cleartool rmname` from command line that will allow the command execution to work even while there are checkouts.
>
> This option forces the removal of the name from the directory when there is at least one checkout of the element, but it does not actually cancel any checkouts of the element.