# cleartool rmelem "has checkout"

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I have a new branch in which I would like to remove some files. I was able to remove some files with this commands:

```
cleartool co -nc .
cleartool rmname <filename>
cleartool ci -nc .
```

But for some other files I get this error:

```
$ ct rmname file
cleartool: Error: Element "file" has checkouts.
```

In my branch, in my view, these files are not checked out. However I can find some checkout with `ct lsco file` in other branches.

Why do I get an error. Removing a file from my branch shouldn't affect the other branches, right?

Can I force the command with `-f` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the `-force` option for the [`cleartool rmname`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rename.htm) command, to get past the fact there are other versions checked out. But that `-force` option might not be available (depending on the `cleartool` version)

I have seen that option in "[Cleartool removing a checkedout file from a folder with rmname](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12350021/6309)" for  `rmname`.

If `rmname -f` works, then it is the way to proceed.
That error message is more about warning the users that, while the file won't be visible anymore, it is still being modified elsewhere.

Comment: Yes it worked with this -force option but I don't understand why ClearCase doesn't allow me to remove a file that is checkedout in another branch

Comment: @coin it is more a warning than an error, really. It warns the user that the file won't be available in the current branch even though it is still being modified in some other branch or versions. Which would render any future merge awkward (the file would be ignored since there would not be any destination version to merge to)